# Удаление файла дата которого меньше заданной

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, вектор

Имеется простенький класс описывающий файл, а именно: имя файла, дата создания, количество обращений к файлу.
Список файлов храню в векторе

код программы на repl.it https://repl.it/@andreykas/HelpfulWhoppingBugs

Программу в принципе написал, но при удалении файлов дата которой меньше заданной возникает исключение и соответственно ошибка в программе, гуглил но все равно не понял что не так, вроде бы код выглядит логично, проблема вот в этом куске кода:

```
if (files_list[i].date.year < delete_date.year) {
        files_list.erase(files_list.begin() + i);
        //vector <file> (files_list).swap(files_list);
    }
```

общий блок удаления файлов дата которой меньше заданной

```
struct_date delete_date;
cout << "Enter delete date: " << endl;
delete_date.input_date();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (files_list[i].date.year < delete_date.year) {
        files_list.erase(files_list.begin() + i);
        //vector <file> (files_list).swap(files_list);
    }
    else if ((files_list[i].date.year == delete_date.year) && (files_list[i].date.month < delete_date.month)) {
        files_list.erase(files_list.begin() + i);
        //vector <file>(files_list).swap(files_list);
    }
    else if ((files_list[i].date.year == delete_date.year) && (files_list[i].date.month == delete_date.month) && (files_list[i].date.day < delete_date.month)) {
        files_list.erase(files_list.begin() + i);
        //vector <file>(files_list).swap(files_list);
    }
}
```

ну и вся "программа"

```
// lab8.cpp : Этот файл содержит функцию "main". Здесь начинается и 
заканчивается выполнение программы.
//

#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class struct_date {
public:
int day;
int month;
int year;

void input_date() {
    cout << "Input day: ";
    cin >> day;
    while ((day > 31) || (day < 1)) {
        cout << "Day must be > 1 and <= 31" << endl;
        cout << "Input day: ";
        cin >> day;
    }

    cout << "Input month: ";
    cin >> month;
    while ((month > 12) || (month < 1)) {
        cout << "Month must be > 1 and <= 12" << endl;
        cout << "Input month: ";
        cin >> month;
    }

    cout << "Input year: ";
    cin >> year;
    while ((year > 2018) || (year < 1000)) {
        cout << "Year must be > 1000 and <= 2018" << endl;
        cout << "Input year: ";
        cin >> year;
    }
}

void output_date() {
    cout << "Date: " << day << "." << month << "." << year << endl;
}


};

class file {
public:
string name;
struct_date date;
int amount;

void input_amount() {
    cout << "Input amount of hits: ";
    cin >> amount;
    while (amount < 0) {
        cout << "Amount must be >= 0" << endl;
        cout << "Input amount of hits: ";
        cin >> amount;
    }
}

void input_name() {
    cout << "Input name of file: ";
    cin >> name;
    while (name == "") {
        cout << "Name cannot be empy" << endl;
        cout << "Input name of file: ";
        cin >> name;
    }
}

void output_name() {
    cout << "Name: " << name << endl;
}

void output_amount() {
    cout << "Amount of hits: " << amount << endl;
}

void output_file() {
    output_name();
    date.output_date();
    output_amount();
    cout << endl;
}

void input_file() {
    input_name();
    date.input_date();
    input_amount();
}
};

int main()
{
//file file1;
//file1.input_file();
//file1.output_file();

int n;


cout << "Input amount of files: ";
cin >> n;

vector <file> files_list(n);

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cout << endl << "Input file #" << i + 1 << ":" << endl;
    files_list[i].input_file();
}

cout << endl << "File catalog: " << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cout << endl << "File #" << i + 1 << ":" << endl;
    files_list[i]. output_file();
}

struct_date delete_date;
cout << "Enter delete date: " << endl;
delete_date.input_date();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (files_list[i].date.year < delete_date.year) {
        files_list.erase(files_list.begin() + i);
        //vector <file> (files_list).swap(files_list);
    }
    else if ((files_list[i].date.year == delete_date.year) && (files_list[i].date.month < delete_date.month)) {
        files_list.erase(files_list.begin() + i);
        //vector <file>(files_list).swap(files_list);
    }
    else if ((files_list[i].date.year == delete_date.year) && (files_list[i].date.month == delete_date.month) && (files_list[i].date.day < delete_date.month)) {
        files_list.erase(files_list.begin() + i);
        //vector <file>(files_list).swap(files_list);
    }
}

int max_amount = -1;
int max_file_amount;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cout << endl << "File #" << i + 1 << ":" << endl;
    files_list[i].output_file();
    if (files_list[i].amount > max_amount) {
        max_amount = files_list[i].amount;
        max_file_amount = i;
    }
}
cout << "File with max amount: " << endl << "File #" << max_file_amount + 1 << endl;
files_list[max_file_amount].output_file();


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы после удаления с помощью **erase** должны отредактировать индекс и размер массива. (*массив изменился.*)

```
...
files_list.erase(files_list.begin() + i);
-- i;
-- n;
...
```

Во всех случаях.

Comment: какая же глупая ошибка... благодарю, надо же было так лохануться...

Comment: Как говорил знакомый мент: Если у вас что-то украли Конкретно, то мы вас ждём... ;)